# How do I parse a mutableList in scala as JSON on play framework 2.0?

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am working on Play Framework 2.0 and it uses Jerkson to parse JSON strings. I was using it successfully to parse Immutable Lists of strings like so:

```
Json.parse( jsonStr ).as[ List[String] ]
```

But this code doesn't work for me when I try

```
Json.parse( jsonStr ).as[ MutableList[String] ]
```

Does anyone know how I can do this easily?

Comment: @missingfaktor I think he's referring to [scala.collection.mutable.MutableList](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/MutableList.html)

Comment: @DanSimon, thanks. Three years of Scala, and this is the first time I am seeing that class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

E.g. `new MutableList[String]() ++= Json.parse( jsonStr ).as[ List[String] ]` (assuming @DanSimon is correct about which `MutableList` you mean). But the most used mutable list-like collection in Scala is a `Buffer` which could be obtained as `Buffer(Json.parse( jsonStr ).as[ List[String] ]` or `Json.parse( jsonStr ).as[ List[String] ].toBuffer`.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that Buffer is the more commonly used mutable list-like collection.

Answer (score 3):

Your second line will work as it is in a future version of Play 2.0, thanks to the replacement of `seqReads` by `traversableReads` [in the current trunk](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/json/Reads.scala):

```
implicit def traversableReads[F[_], A](implicit bf: generic.CanBuildFrom[F[_], A, F[A]], ra: Reads[A]) = new Reads[F[A]] {
  def reads(json: JsValue) = json match {
    case JsArray(ts) => {
      val builder = bf()
      for (a <- ts.map(fromJson[A](_))) {
        builder += a
      }
      builder.result()
    }
    case _ => throw new RuntimeException("Collection expected")
  }
}
```

So if you're willing [to build Play from source](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/BuildingFromSource), or to wait, you're fine. Otherwise you should be able to drop the method above somewhere in your own code to get an appropriate `Reads` instance in scope, or—even better—just use Alexey Romanov's solution, or—best of all—don't use `MutableList`.

Comment: Sorry, but where exactly should I put this method in my code?

Comment: It's an implicit method that creates an instance of the `Reads` [type class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5408861/what-are-type-classes-in-scala-useful-for) for collection types as needed, so you should be able to put it anywhere in scope (you may need to add an import for—or qualify the call to—`Json.fromJson`).