# Scala adding stackable properties to classes

Tags: scala, design-patterns

I have a simple class Feature, currently implemented as a case class

```
case class Feature(value :String)
```

There are multiple operations decorating a feature with different properties, for example there is a function that might count the number of appearances of the feature so then I might need a CountedFeature. Besides counting I might need also a WeightedFeature, an IndexedFeature and so on.

My intuition says it's suitable for traits so I defined the following traits

```
trait Counted {def count :Long}
trait Weighted {def weight :Double}
trait Indexed {def index :Int}
```

Two issues pop up with this:
1. Do I need to create a concrete class implementing each combination of traits (e.x. implement a CountedWeightedFeature, CountedIndexedfeature and so on) ,or is there some way to avoid it. If I will move to more decorations it will be impossible to mantain classes for all combinations.
2. I want to design a function that weights features based on their count. It's signature should look something like :

```
def computeWeightsByCount(features :List[T <: Feature with Counted]) :List[T with Weighted] = {...}
```

T here may be Indexed or not, so this function should have some way to take a class and instansiate a new class that has all the traits of the original class stacked inside plus an additional one.

Is there some elegant way to do this in Scala, or should I totaly rethink this design?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The design looks fine to me, except extending case classes is not recommended. A brief summary of the reasons why can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12705634/2186890

So you will might want to rewrite `Feature` as something like this:

```
trait Feature { def value: String }
```

Now you can define case classes for pattern matching etc. like this:

```
case class CountedFeature(value: String, count: Long) extends Feature with Counted
```

There is no easy way to avoid combinatorial explosion of case classes like this, but you are enabled to use types such as `Feature with Counted` wherever you like. Keep in mind that you can easily create objects that match type `Feature with Counted` on the fly. For instance:

```
val x: Feature with Counted = new Feature with Counted { val value = ""; val count = 0L }
```

Implementing `computeWeightsByCount` like you want is a little tricky, because there is no easy way to build a `T with Weighted` without knowing more about type `T`. But it can be done with implicit methods. Essentially, we need to have a defined path for generating a `T with Weighted` from a `T` for every `Feature with Counted` that you want to apply this method to. For instance, we start with this:

```
trait Feature { def value: String }
trait Counted { def count: Long }
trait Weighted { def weight: Double }
trait Indexed { def index: Int }
```

We want to define `computeWeightsByCount` like you did in your question, but also taking an implicit method that takes a `T` and a weight, and produces a `T with Weighted`:

```
def computeWeightsByCount[
  T <: Feature with Counted](                                                                                       
  features: List[T])(
  implicit weighted: (T, Double) => T with Weighted
): List[T with Weighted] = {  
  def weight(fc: Feature with Counted): Double = 0.0d
  features map { f => weighted(f, weight(f)) }
}
```

Now we need to define an implicit method to produce weighted features from the input features. Let's start with getting a `Feature with Counted with Weighted` from a `Feature with Counted`. We'll put it in companion object for `Feature`:

```
object Feature {
  implicit def weight(fc: Feature with Counted, weight: Double): Feature with Counted with Weighted = {
    case class FCW(value: String, count: Long, weight: Double) extends Feature with Counted with Weighted
    FCW(fc.value, fc.count, weight)
  }
}
```

We can use it like so:

```
case class FC(value: String, count: Long) extends Feature with Counted
val fcs: List[Feature with Counted] = List(FC("0", 0L), FC("1", 1L))
val fcws: List[Feature with Counted with Weighted] = computeWeightsByCount[Feature with Counted](fcs)
```

For any type that you want to compute weighted counts for, you need to define a similar such implicit method.

Admittedly, this is far from a beautiful solution. So yes, you are right, you may want to rethink the design. The advantage to this approach, however, is that any further extensions to the `Feature` "hierarchy" can be made without needing to make any changes to `computeWeightsByCount`. Whoever writes the new trait can provide the appropriate implicit methods as well.