# Scala case class inheritance with code reusability

Tags: scala, inheritance

I am trying to model my class hierarchy in case classes. I appreciate related [discussion about duplication of case class properties here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12705309/scala-case-class-inheritance).

Consider the class hierarchy shown below.

```
trait Super {
  def a:String
}

case class Child1(a:String, b:String) extends Super {
  override def toString = s" a = $a, b= $b"

}

case class Child2(a:String, c:String) extends Super {
  override def toString = s" a = $a, c= $c"
}
```

I have a scenario where I want to construct case class objects using basic properties like `a`, `b`, `c` as well as using XML. I created companion objects for these case classes as below.

```
object Child1 {    
   def apply(node: scala.xml.Node): Child1 = {
      val a = (node \ "a").text
      val b = (node \ "b").text
      Child1(a, b)
  }
}


object Child2 {
    def apply(node: scala.xml.Node): Child2 = {
      val a = (node \ "a").text
      val c = (node \ "c").text
      Child2(a, c)
  }
}
```

In above code, I have to duplicate the line that parses value of `a` - `(node \ "a").text`. There doesn't seem to be a way to do the same even if I convert `Super` to an `abstract` superclass.

I wonder how one can do this, which I could have done very easily using abstract class and couple of constructors in `Super` class in Java.

UPDATE: Qualified name for scala.xml.Node type.

Comment: I fixed Child2.apply to return an instance of Child2 instead of Child1. I assume this was a copy + paste mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed this is not possible with a case class. You will have to define a helper to get rid of the duplication like this.

```
Child1(Super.getAValue(node), c)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a trivial task for [scala.macros](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/overview.html) or [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless)

Lets define generic xml extractor

```
import scala.xml.Node

trait Extract[L] extends (scala.xml.Node => L)
```

And it's simple implementation for string-only containing `HList` [record](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#extensible-records)s:

```
import shapeless._
import shapeless.labelled._

implicit object extractHNil extends Extract[HNil] {
  def apply(node: Node): HNil = HNil
}

implicit def extractHCons[K <: Symbol, L <: HList]
(implicit witness: Witness.Aux[K], recur: Extract[L]) =
  new Extract[FieldType[K, String] :: L] {
    def apply(node: Node): ::[FieldType[K, String], L] = {
      val name = witness.value.name
      val value = (node \ name).text
      field[K](value) :: recur(node)
    }
  }
```

Now you can construct case class extractor build on top of [LabelledGeneric](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#generic-representation-of-sealed-families-of-case-classes):

```
implicit def extractCase[C, L]
(implicit lgen: LabelledGeneric.Aux[C, L], extract: Extract[L]) =
  new Extract[C] {
    def apply(node: Node): C = lgen.from(extract(node))
  }
```

From this point you can add simple mixin for your companions:

```
abstract trait XmlReader[C] {
  def extract: Extract[C]
  def apply(node: scala.xml.Node) = extract(node)
}
```

And implement your builders as

```
object Child1 extends XmlReader[Child1] {
  val extract: Extract[Child1] = implicitly
}

object Child2 extends XmlReader[Child2] {
  val extract: Extract[Child2] = implicitly
}
```

Now you can verify it:

```
val node = <node>
  <a>1</a>
  <b>2</b>
  <c>3</c>
</node>

println(Child1(node)) // a = 1, b= 2
println(Child2(node)) // a = 1, c= 3
```

Note that it's not very hard task to extend such parsers for work with nearly anything defined via  sealed families of case classes. See [picopickle](https://github.com/netvl/picopickle) as example of generic parser built with shapeless

Answer (score 0):

define a method `superA` do it

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

trait Super {
  def a: String
}

trait Node {
  def \(s: String): String = s
}

object Node {
  // also you can move it to Super companion object 
  implicit class SuperMethodA(val node: Node) {
    def superA = node \ "a"
  }

}

case class Child1(a: String, b: String) extends Super {
  override def toString = s" a = $a, b= $b"

}
object Child1{
  def apply(node: Node): Child1 = {
    val a = node.superA //.text
    val b = (node \ "b") //.text
    Child1(a, b)
  }
}

case class Child2(a: String, c: String) extends Super {
  override def toString = s" a = $a, c= $c"


}
object Child2{
  def apply(node: Node): Child2 = {
    val a = node.superA //.text
    val c = (node \ "c") //.text
    Child2(a, c)
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I intended to use scala.xml.Node, source code of which is not my control.