# If I have case classes with allot of properties in common, should I use inheritance?

Tags: scala, inheritance, case-class

I am a order management system that has models that have many fields that are common amongst the classes.

```scala
ProductType1(p1: String, p2: String, p3: String, ....)
ProductType2(p1: String, p2: String, p3: String, ....)
ProductType3(p1: String, p2: String, p3: String, ....)
```

where `p1`, `p2`, `p3` are common and then there are properties that are unique to each case class.

Is the best practise to use inheritance or just duplicate the properties?

Comment: The flag "opinion-based" seems excessive. You might want to have a look to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12705309/scala-case-class-inheritance anyway in Scala case class inheritance is not possible, thus you don't really have the choice.