# Type upper bounds and inheritance

Tags: scala

Let's assume we have a class Pair and some tree of inheritance:

```
class Pair[ T <: Comparable[T] ](r:T,t:T) {

  def sizeRelationship = r.compareTo(t)
}

sealed class Person(val importance:Int) extends Comparable[Person] {
  override def compareTo(o: Person): Int = ???
}

class Student extends Person(10)
class Teacher extends Person(50)
```

Now how to modify the upper to be able to create a Pair[Student]?

```
val mixed: Pair[Person] = new Pair(new Student,new Teacher) /* compiles */
val notMixed = new Pair[Student](new Student, new Student) /* Student does not conform to Comparable */
```

Comment: look here for the clues: http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/lower-type-bounds.html

Comment: You cannot create _any_ `Pair[Student]` because `Student` violates the type requirements for `Pair`'s `T`. `Student is not <: Comparable[Student]` but only `<: Comparable[Person]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this helps:

```
val notMixed = new Pair(new Student, (new Student).asInstanceOf[Person])
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is the following:

```
class Pair[ T <% Comparable[T] ](r:T,t:T) {

  def sizeRelationship = r.compareTo(t)
}
```

Note the *viewable-as* **<%** in place of the *subtype-of* **<:**

```
sealed class Person(val importance:Int) {
  def compareTo(o: Person): Int = ???
}

class Student extends Person(10)
class Teacher extends Person(50)

implicit class PersonComparable[T <: Person](x: T) extends Comparable[T] {
  def compareTo(o: T): Int = x.compareTo(o)
}

val mixed: Pair[Person] = new Pair(new Student,new Teacher) /* compiles */
val notMixed = new Pair[Student](new Student, new Student) /* compiles */
```

The main difference with the original code is that in place of inheriting (implementing) the Comparable trait, the domain classes are *retrofitted* with it, by means of an [implicit class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5408861/what-are-type-classes-in-scala-useful-for). This makes it possible to exhibit the polymorphic behavior that is required by the type signature of:

```
val notMixed = new Pair[Student](...)
```

The main practical advantage versus the solution of using the base type signature in the Pair instance:

```
val notMixed = new Pair[Person](...)
```

is more accurate typing of the Pair instances, which in turn can enable more sophisticated processing downstream (e.g. pattern matching, etc).