# Scala generic cast from String function

Tags: scala, generics, casting

How can I write a function to convert a String to a generic type (Double, Int, Float, etc.)?

Here's pseudocode for the functionality I'm looking for:

```
def castFromString[A: Manifest](value: String): A = {
  if (A == Double) {
    parseDouble(value)
  } else if (A == Int) {
    parseInt(value)
  } else {
    value.toString()
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you meant `A: ClassTag`/`A: TypeTag`, `Manifest`s are kind of deprecated. Check [this guide](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/typetags-manifests.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to write the function as such with `Manifest`, `ClassTag` or a `TypeTag` as they can only tell you the type at runtime. For something like the pseudocode function to work, the return type must be known at compile time.

However, could implement the function by defining a [type class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5408861/what-are-type-classes-in-scala-useful-for) and writing instances for the types you wish to cast from. Here's an example:

```scala
import java.lang.Double.parseDouble
import java.lang.Integer.parseInt

trait CastableFromString[A] {
  def fromString(string: String): A
}

object CastableFromString {
  implicit object DoubleCastableFromString extends CastableFromString[Double] {
    override def fromString(string: String): Double =
      parseDouble(string)
  }

  implicit object IntCastableFromString extends CastableFromString[Int] {
    override def fromString(string: String): Int =
      parseInt(string)
  }

  implicit object IntListCastableFromString extends CastableFromString[List[Int]] {
    override def fromString(string: String): List[Int] =
      string.split(',').map(parseInt).toList
  }

  def castFromString[A](string: String)(implicit cast: CastableFromString[A]): A =
    cast.fromString(string)
}

object Main {
  import CastableFromString._

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val d = castFromString[Double]("4.5")
    val i = castFromString[Int]("42")
    val li = castFromString[List[Int]]("1,2,3")
    println(s"d=$d i=$i li=$li")
  }
}
```

Alternatively, to get closer to something that resembles your pseudocode, you could use a [macro](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/overview.html). Here's an example (won't work on anything older than Scala 2.11):

```scala
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox.Context

class StringCasterImpl(val c: Context) {
  def castFromStringImpl[A: c.WeakTypeTag](string: c.Expr[String]): c.Tree = {
    import c.universe._
    val t = c.weakTypeOf[A]
    if (t =:= typeOf[Double]) {
      q"java.lang.Double.parseDouble($string)"
    } else if (t =:= typeOf[Int]) {
      q"java.lang.Integer.parseInt($string)"
    } else if (t =:= typeOf[List[Int]]) {
      q"$string.split(',').map(java.lang.Integer.parseInt).toList"
    } else {
      c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, s"Don't know how to cast $t to String")
    }
  }
}

object StringCaster {
  def castFromString[A](string: String): A =
    macro StringCasterImpl.castFromStringImpl[A]
}

// note that this object must be in a separate compilation unit
object Main {
  import StringCaster._

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val d = castFromString[Double]("4.2")
    val i = castFromString[Int]("42")
    val li = castFromString[List[Int]]("1,2,3")
    println(s"d=$d i=$i li=$li")
  }
}
```

Comment: I like scala, but this is just one of those several "craptastic broken windows" where java does it much better with a one word solution (instead of requiring a hierarchy of objects/classes).

Answer (score 0):

You can define implicit functions that converts string to specific type.

Then when required it will automatically casted.

```
math.max(1,"3") // throws error
```

but now

```
implicit def StringToInt(x: String): Int = x

math.max(1,"3")  //>> 3
```

Comment: This level of implicits is very dangerous imho.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it exactly this way, you can match the `runtimeClass` in the `ClassTag`:

```
def castFromString[A: ClassTag](value: String): A = {
  val c = implicitly[ClassTag[A]].runtimeClass
  if(c == classOf[Double]) parseDouble(value).asInstanceOf[A]
  else ...
}
```

Note the need for an `asInstanceOf` cast. The typeclass approach suggested by @Olli is safer and more idiomatic.