# generic collection generation with a generic type

Tags: scala, generics, collections, implicit

Sometimes, I find myself wishing scala collections to include some missing functionality, and it's rather easy "extending" a collection, and provide a custom method.

This is a bit more difficult when it comes to building the collection from scratch.
Consider useful methods such as `.iterate`.
I'll demonstrate the usecase with a similar, familiar function: `unfold`.

`unfold` is a method to construct a collection from an initial state `z: S`, and a function to generate an optional tuple of the next state, and an element `E`, or an empty option indicating the end.

the method signature, for some collection type `Coll[T]` should look roughly like:

```
def unfold[S,E](z: S)(f: S ⇒ Option[(S,E)]): Coll[E]
```

Now, IMO, the most "natural" usage should be, e.g:

```
val state: S = ??? // initial state
val arr: Array[E] = Array.unfold(state){ s ⇒
  // code to convert s to some Option[(S,E)]
  ???
}
```

This is pretty straight forward to do for a specific collection type:

```
implicit class ArrayOps(arrObj: Array.type) {
  def unfold[S,E : ClassTag](z: S)(f: S => Option[(S,E)]): Array[E] = {
    val b = Array.newBuilder[E]
    var s = f(z)
    while(s.isDefined) {
      val Some((state,element)) = s
      b += element
      s = f(state)
    }
    b.result()
  }
}
```

with this implicit class in scope, we can generate an array for the Fibonacci seq like this:

```
val arr: Array[Int] = Array.unfold(0->1) {
  case (a,b) if a < 256 => Some((b -> (a+b)) -> a)
  case _                => None
}
```

But if we want to provide this functionality to all other collection types, I see no other option than to C&P the code, and replace all `Array` occurrences with `List`,`Seq`,etc'...

So I tried another approach:

```
trait BuilderProvider[Elem,Coll] {
  def builder: mutable.Builder[Elem,Coll]
}

object BuilderProvider {
  object Implicits {
    implicit def arrayBuilderProvider[Elem : ClassTag] = new BuilderProvider[Elem,Array[Elem]] {
      def builder = Array.newBuilder[Elem]
    }
    implicit def listBuilderProvider[Elem : ClassTag] = new BuilderProvider[Elem,List[Elem]] {
      def builder = List.newBuilder[Elem]
    }
    // many more logicless implicits
  }
}

def unfold[Coll,S,E : ClassTag](z: S)(f: S => Option[(S,E)])(implicit bp: BuilderProvider[E,Coll]): Coll = {
  val b = bp.builder
  var s = f(z)
  while(s.isDefined) {
    val Some((state,element)) = s
    b += element
    s = f(state)
  }
  b.result()
}
```

Now, with the above in scope, all one needs is an import for the right type:

```
import BuilderProvider.Implicits.arrayBuilderProvider

val arr: Array[Int] = unfold(0->1) {
  case (a,b) if a < 256 => Some((b -> (a+b)) -> a)
  case _                => None
}
```

but this doesn't fell right also. I don't like forcing the user to import something, let alone an implicit method that will create a useless wiring class on every method call. Moreover, there is no easy way to override the default logic. You can think about collections such as `Stream`, where it would be most appropriate to create the collection lazily, or other special implementation details to consider regarding other collections.

The best solution I could come up with, was to use the first solution as a template, and generate the sources with sbt:

```
sourceGenerators in Compile += Def.task {
  val file = (sourceManaged in Compile).value / "myextensions" / "util" / "collections" / "package.scala"
  val colls = Seq("Array","List","Seq","Vector","Set") //etc'...
  val prefix = s"""package myextensions.util
    |
    |package object collections {
    |
    """.stripMargin
  val all = colls.map{ coll =>
    s"""
    |implicit class ${coll}Ops[Elem](obj: ${coll}.type) {
    |  def unfold[S,E : ClassTag](z: S)(f: S => Option[(S,E)]): ${coll}[E] = {
    |    val b = ${coll}.newBuilder[E]
    |    var s = f(z)
    |    while(s.isDefined) {
    |      val Some((state,element)) = s
    |      b += element
    |      s = f(state)
    |    }
    |    b.result()
    |  }
    |}
    """.stripMargin
  }
  IO.write(file,all.mkString(prefix,"\n","\n}\n"))
  Seq(file)
}.taskValue
```

But this solution suffers from other issues, and is hard to maintain. just imagine if `unfold` is not the only function to add globally, and overriding default implementation is still hard. bottom line, this is hard to maintain and does not "feel" right either.

So, is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let's make a basic implementation of the function, which uses an explicit `Builder` argument. In case of unfold it can look like this:

```
import scala.language.higherKinds
import scala.annotation.tailrec
import scala.collection.GenTraversable
import scala.collection.mutable
import scala.collection.generic.{GenericCompanion, CanBuildFrom}

object UnfoldImpl {
  def unfold[CC[_], E, S](builder: mutable.Builder[E, CC[E]])(initial: S)(next: S => Option[(S, E)]): CC[E] = {
    @tailrec
    def build(state: S): CC[E] = {
      next(state) match {
        case None => builder.result()
        case Some((nextState, elem)) =>
          builder += elem
          build(nextState)
      }
    }

    build(initial)
  }
}
```

Now, what can be an easy way to get a builder of a collection by its type?

I can propose two possibile solutions. The first is to make an implicit extension class, that extends a [`GenericCompanion`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.7/index.html#scala.collection.generic.GenericCompanion) – the common superclass of most scala's built-in collections. This `GenericCompanion` has a method `newBuilder` that returns a `Builder` for the provided element type. An implementation may look like this:

```
implicit class Unfolder[CC[X] <: GenTraversable[X]](obj: GenericCompanion[CC]) {
  def unfold[S, E](initial: S)(next: S => Option[(S, E)]): CC[E] =
    UnfoldImpl.unfold(obj.newBuilder[E])(initial)(next)
}
```

And it's very easy to use this:

```
scala> List.unfold(1)(a => if (a > 10) None else Some(a + 1, a * a))
res1: List[Int] = List(1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100)
```

One drawback is that some collections don't have companion objects extending `GenericCompanion`. For example, `Array`, or user-defined collections.

Another possible solution is to use an implicit 'builder provider', like you have proposed. And scala already has such a thing in the collection library. It's [`CanBuildFrom`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.7/index.html#scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom). An implementation with a `CanBuildFrom` may look like this:

```
object Unfolder2 {
  def apply[CC[_]] = new {
    def unfold[S, E](initial: S)(next: S => Option[(S, E)])(
      implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[CC[E], E, CC[E]]
    ): CC[E] =
      UnfoldImpl.unfold(cbf())(initial)(next)
  }
}
```

Usage example:

```
scala> Unfolder2[Array].unfold(1)(a => if (a > 10) None else Some(a + 1, a * a))
res1: Array[Int] = Array(1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100)
```

This works with scala's collections, `Array`, and may work with user-defined collections, if the user has provided a `CanBuildFrom` instance.

---

Note, that both approaches won't work with `Stream`s in a lazy fashion. That's mostly because the original implementation `UnfoldImpl.unfold` uses a `Builder`, which for a `Stream` is [eager](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.7/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Stream$$StreamBuilder).

To do something like unfolding for `Stream` lazily, you can't use the standard `Builder`. You'd have to provide a separate implementation using `Stream.cons` (or `#::`). To be able to choose an implementation automatically, depending on the collection type requested by user, you can use the typeclass pattern. Here is a sample implementation:

```
trait Unfolder3[E, CC[_]] {
  def unfold[S](initial: S)(next: S => Option[(S, E)]): CC[E]
}

trait UnfolderCbfInstance {
  // provides unfolder for types that have a `CanBuildFrom`
  // this is used only if the collection is not a `Stream`
  implicit def unfolderWithCBF[E, CC[_]](
    implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[CC[E], E, CC[E]]
  ): Unfolder3[E, CC] =
    new Unfolder3[E, CC] {
      def unfold[S](initial: S)(next: S => Option[(S, E)]): CC[E] =
        UnfoldImpl.unfold(cbf())(initial)(next)
    }
}

object Unfolder3 extends UnfolderCbfInstance {
  // lazy implementation, that overrides `unfolderWithCbf` for `Stream`s
  implicit def streamUnfolder[E]: Unfolder3[E, Stream] =
    new Unfolder3[E, Stream] {
      def unfold[S](initial: S)(next: S => Option[(S, E)]): Stream[E] =
        next(initial).fold(Stream.empty[E]) {
          case (state, elem) =>
            elem #:: unfold(state)(next)
        }
    }

  def apply[CC[_]] = new {
    def unfold[E, S](initial: S)(next: S => Option[(S, E)])(
      implicit impl: Unfolder3[E, CC]
    ): CC[E] = impl.unfold(initial)(next)
  }
}
```

Now this implementation works eagerly for normal collections (including `Array` and user-defined collections with appropriate `CanBuildFrom`), and lazily for `Stream`s:

```
scala> Unfolder3[Array].unfold(1)(a => if (a > 10) None else Some(a + 1, a * a))
res0: Array[Int] = Array(1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100)

scala> com.Main.Unfolder3[Stream].unfold(1)(a => if (a > 10) None else { println(a); Some(a + 1, a * a) })
1
res2: Stream[Int] = Stream(1, ?)

scala> res2.take(3).toList
2
3
res3: List[Int] = List(1, 4, 9)
```

Note, that if `Unfolder3.apply` is moved to another object or class, the user won't have to import anything to do with `Unfolder3` at all.

If you don't understand how this implementation works you can read something about the [typeclass patern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5408861/what-are-type-classes-in-scala-useful-for) in Scala, and the [order of implicit resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598085/where-does-scala-look-for-implicits).

Comment: Thanks! regarding the `Stream`, I'm not very familiar with it, but maybe there is a way to enhance your solution with `@specialized`? (if it's not too much to ask, I would love to see a working example)

Comment: @giladhoch I've added an example how to work with `Stream`s lazily

Comment: Thank you very much! I couldn't have hoped for a more complete and thorough answer. I learned a lot here.