# List of elements implementing typeclass A and B in Scala

Tags: scala, typeclass

I got the following issue when trying to use typeclasses throughout my project.

```
trait FooAble[T] { def fa(t: T): List[T] }
object Foo { def apply[T](t: T) = implicitly[FooAble[T]].fa(t) }

trait BarAble[T] { def fb(t: T): Double }
object Bar { def apply[T](t: T) = implicitly[BarAble[T]].fb(t) }
```

And would like to be able to do the following:

```
// xs contains elements of type A and B which are subclasses of the trait Something
def f(xs: List[Something]) = {
  val something = xs.map(Foo)
  val somethingElse = xs.map(Bar)
}
```

However, this would not work as we don't know if `Something` implements `A[]`and `B[]`, no implicit implementation found. What do I need to do so that the elements of the list `xs` implement the typeclasses `FooAble` and `BarAble`?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do here?

Answer (score 0):

I think this question: [What are type classes in Scala useful for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5408861/what-are-type-classes-in-scala-useful-for) will help you to understand the proper use (& usefulness) of type classes.

Am just extending the answer by Kevin Wright in the above link for your use case (if I understand your need correctly!):

```
trait Addable[T] {
    def zero: T
    def append(a: T, b: T): T
}

trait Productable[T] {
    def zero: T
    def product(a: T, b: T): T
  }

implicit object IntIsAddable extends Addable[Int] {
    def zero = 0
    def append(a: Int, b: Int) = a + b
  }

implicit object IntIsProductable extends Productable[Int] {
    def zero = 1
    def product(a: Int, b: Int) = a*b
  } 

def sumAndProduct[T](xs: List[T])(implicit addable: Addable[T], productable: Productable[T]) =
    (xs.foldLeft(addable.zero)(addable.append), xs.foldLeft(productable.zero)(productable.product))
```

So akin to above, in your use case, you need to provide implicit objects which implement your type classes FooAble & BarAble and your method signature for function `f` becomes:

```
def f[Something](xs: List[Something])(implicit fooable: FooAble[Something], barable: BarAble[Something])
```